# Bar Plot does not Display in Shiny App, I have developed a code

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to the shiny app and trying to write simple code.
I changed the codes so many times but my bar chart doesn't work.
I have this problem in my other trying. That the UI works and also the codes in the server work part by part in R but not in the shiny app. I know some part of my server is not what I want, I just want to know what should I do to run the code which works in R but not in Shiny

```
#Graph 2
server<-#Graph 2
library("tidyverse")
library("leaflet")
library("leaflet.extras")
library("rnaturalearthdata")
library("sf")
library("DT")
library("ggplot2")

N <- read.csv("https://data.ontario.ca/dataset/f4112442-bdc8-45d2-be3c-12efae72fb27/resource/455fd63b-603d-4608-8216-7d8647f43350/download/conposcovidloc.csv")


function(input, output, session){
 

  if(input$data.Gender){

     City ="Ottawa"
     
     N %>% subset(Reporting_PHU_City == City) %>%
       select(Case_Reported_Date, Age_Group, Client_Gender, Outcome1)%>%
       rename(Date = Case_Reported_Date)%>%
       arrange(Age_Group, Client_Gender, Outcome1)
     
     
     Data.N <- as.data.frame(N)
     Data.N %>%
       group_by(Age_Group) %>%
       summarise(Age = n_distinct(Age_Group)) %>%
       arrange(desc(Age))
     
     w = table(N$Age_Group)
     
     t = as.data.frame(w)

 }
 
 output$Plot <- renderPlot({

       ggplot() +
         geom_bar(stat = "identity",data = t,mapping = aes(x = N$Client_Gender , y =Freq))
   
 })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the site didn't let me share the UI too. This is Ui

```
UI<- #Graph 2

library("leaflet")
library("DT")

fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons("data.Gender", "",
                   c("Data female" = "Gender.Female",
                     "Data male" = "Gender.Male"))
    ),

  

    enter code here
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("Plot")
      )
  ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should group by `Client_Gender`.  Your present group by of `Age_Group` will give 1 as the value for all groups.

Try this

```
server <- function(input, output, session){

 t <- reactive({
    input$data.Gender
   
    City ="Toronto"

    aa <- N %>% subset(Reporting_PHU_City == City) %>%
      select(Case_Reported_Date, Age_Group, Client_Gender, Outcome1)%>%
      rename(Date = Case_Reported_Date)%>%
      arrange(Age_Group, Client_Gender, Outcome1)

    bb <- aa %>%
      group_by(Client_Gender) %>%
      summarise(Age = n_distinct(Age_Group)) %>%
      arrange(desc(Age))
    
    bb
  })
 

  output$Plot <- renderPlot({

    ggplot(data=t()) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity",mapping = aes(x = Client_Gender , y = Age))

  })

}
```

[image: output]